# Как из корутины получить ссылку на instance ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, coroutine

В приложении, основанном на Compose, есть ViewModel:

`class ViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {}`
.

Из него по нажатию кнопки запускается корутина, оторванная от главного потока, в которой выполняется функция function():

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    function()
}
```

.

Вопрос:
есть ли возможность внутри фнкции function(), работающей в отдельной корутине, получить ссылку на уже существующий instance ViewModel (на момент запуска корутины ViewModel уже создан)?
Главное то, что корутина, в которой работает function(), не Activity и не Fragment, поэтому в ней не работают варианты типа

by viewModels()

или

by activityViewModels().

Главная цель всего этого - получить возможность запускать другие функции ViewModel из этой корутины, чтобы иметь возможность передавать промежуточные данные из корутины во время ее выполнения в основной поток.

И какие еще есть варианты обмена данными между отделенной от главного потока корутиной и главным потоком?

Comment: Не вполне понятны ваши затруднения. Ко рутина в классе у вас метод вызывает. Метод имеет доступ к классу в котором вызван. Возможно вам нужны какие-то другие классы, от других экранов?

Comment: В функции function(), которая работает в оторванной от главного потока корутине, происходят операции backup/restore с базой данных, в течение которых хочется передавать промежуточные данные (строку) во viewmodel, откуда эти данные уже можно будет отображать в интерфейсе. То есть чтобы был виден ход процесса backup/restore.

Comment: Я даже ссылку на функцию отображения viewmodel передавал в корутину, но приложение крашилось, так как корутина не в главном потоке и он по этой ссылке ничего не находил. Теперь появилась идея инжектить экземпляр viewmodel в функцию function() в корутине, так же как это делается в Compose-функции с помощью vewModel(). Но пока не понял как это можно сделать, и можно ли вообще, если function() - это отдельная функция, не activity и не fragment, да ещё и не в главном потоке.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, вам нужно что-то такое:

1. Во ViewModel разместите какой-то наблюдаемый из View источник данных. Например так:

   ```
    val someState = MutableStateFlow("")
   ```
2. Внутри корутины в него что-то передавайте:

   ```
    someState.tryEmit("something")
   ```
3. Во View как-то реагируйте на изменения в someState (упрощённый пример без Compose, просто в активити/фрагменте)

   ```
    lifecycleScope.launch { viewModel.someState.collect { System.out.println(it) } }
   ```